# NetBeans 8.1 (on Mac OS) PHP Autocompletion with $this->var does not work

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

Strange autocomplete behaviour:

```
class myFirstClass
{
  public function myFunc1() {}
  public function myFunc2() {}
}

class mySecondClass
{
  /**
   * @return myFirstClass
   */
  public function getMyFirstClass()
  {
    return new myFirstClass();
  }

  public function init()
  {
    $myFirstClass = new myFirstClass();
    $myFirstClass-> // autoComplete works here and shows myFunc1 and myFunc2

    $this->myFirstClass = new myFirstClass();
    $this->myFirstClass-> // autoComplete does not work here

    $this->getMyFirstClass()-> // autoComplete works here and shows myFunc1 and myFunc2 

    $this->myFirstClass2 = $this->getMyFirstClass();
    $this->myFirstClass2-> // autoComplete does not work here

    $this->myFirstClass2->myFunc1(); // cmd+click on myFunc1() in this line jumps to the myFunc1-function in myFirstClass, so netbeans "knows" the right class, but doesn't autocomplete :(
  }
}
```

Without the $this the Code-Autocomplete works as supposed, but with $this-> it shows nothing anymore. Is this a known NetBeans bug or is there a setting to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess NetBeans only has an autocompletion for `$this->....`, not for `$this->....->....`, so it has no support for anything after the first arrow. You're correct it's not working, because it isn't intended to.

Regards.

Comment: thank you, but this seems not to be the problem. I added a working example with two arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Please add fields to your mySecondClass:

```
class mySecondClass {

    private $myFirstClass;
    private $myFirstClass2;

}
```

or

```
class mySecondClass {

    /**
     * @var myFirstClass 
     */
    private $myFirstClass;

    /**
     * @var myFirstClass 
     */
    private $myFirstClass2;

}
```

Comment: irrelevant, this doesn't change anything ;)

Comment: It works in my environment (NB81 on Linux). Please try adding PHPDoc comments (UPDATED).